# How do I add more than one Slideshow on the same page using modals?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, slideshow

I created modals on my website and I am trying to add different slideshows on each modal.

With this code, I get the same slideshow on each modal but just with some slides added.
I want to add slideshows that don't affect the others.

How can I do this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="experience-list exper1">
  <img src="" class="exp-image" />
  <button class="overlay" id="myBtn" data-modal="myModal">

    <div class="exper-details">
      <div class="exper-title"></div>
      <div class="exper-info"></div>
    </div>
  </button>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext"><!--1 / 3--></div>
          <img src="" />

        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="" />

        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="" />

        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-info">
        <div class="modal-details">
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="experience-list exper2">
  <img src="" class="exp-image" />
  <button class="overlay" id="myBtn2" data-modal="myModal2">

    <div class="exper-details">
      <div class="exper-title"></div>
      <div class="exper-info"></div>
    </div>
  </button>
  <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext"><!--1 / 3--></div>
          <img src="" />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="" />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="" />
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-info">
        <div class="modal-details">
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<!--MODAL-->

<script>
    var modalBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".overlay")];
    modalBtns.forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.onclick = function () {
            var modal = btn.getAttribute('data-modal');

            document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
        }
    });

    var closeBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".close")];
    closeBtns.forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.onclick = function () {
            var modal = btn.closest('.modal');
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    });

    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target.className === "modal") {
            event.target.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<!--SLIDESHOW-->
<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

HERE IS MY MODAL CODE ADDED TO PREVIOUS QUESTION
MODAL

```
<!--MODAL-->
<script>
    var modalBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".overlay")];
    modalBtns.forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.onclick = function () {
            var modal = btn.getAttribute('data-modal');

            document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
        }
    });

    var closeBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".close")];
    closeBtns.forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.onclick = function () {
            var modal = btn.closest('.modal');
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    });

    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target.className === "modal") {
            event.target.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

MODAL CSS

```
/* MODAL */

.modal {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    /*padding-top: 100px;*/
    margin-top:100px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100vw;
    height: 750px;
    overflow:auto;
    /*background-color: rgb(0,0,0);*/
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #252C3C;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    /*border: 1px solid #888;*/
    width: 50%;
    height: 720px;
}


.modal-info {
    border-top: 3px solid #252C3C;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right:20px;

}
.modal-info h1 {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.modal-info h4 {
    font-size: 18px;

}

.modal-details {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.modal-info p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.modal-info a {
    padding: 11px 30px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: all .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #E31B6D;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 0;
}

.close {
    color: #252C3C;
    float:right;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:fixed;
    left:74%;
    top:82%;
}


.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color:pink;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: You want separate modals with separate carousels?

Comment: Yes, I managed to make separate modals but not the slideshows.

Comment: formatting code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this =>

In javascript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex, "mySlides");
showSlides(slideIndex, "mySlides2");

    function plusSlides(n, slide) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n, slide);
    }

    function currentSlide(n, slide) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n, slide);
    }

function showSlides(n, slide ) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName(slide);
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        //dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
```

In html:

```
<div class="experience-list exper1">
                <img src="" class="exp-image" />
                <button class="overlay" id="myBtn" data-modal="myModal">

                    <div class="exper-details">
                        <div class="exper-title"></div>
                        <div class="exper-info">
                    </div>
                </button>
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">


                        <div class="slideshow-container">
                            <div class="mySlides fade">
                                <div class="numbertext"><!--1 / 3--></div>
                                <img src="" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="mySlides fade">
                                <div class="numbertext"></div>
                                <img src="" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="mySlides fade">
                                <div class="numbertext"></div>
                                <img src="" />

                            </div>

                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,'mySlides')">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1,'mySlides')">&#10095;</a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-info">
                            <div class="modal-details">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="experience-list exper2">
                <img src="" class="exp-image" />
                <button class="overlay" id="myBtn2" data-modal="myModal2">

                    <div class="exper-details">
                        <div class="exper-title"></div>
                        <div class="exper-info"></div>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">


                        <div class="slideshow-container">
                            <div class="mySlides2 fade">
                                <div class="numbertext"><!--1 / 3--></div>
                                <img src="" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="mySlides2 fade">
                                <div class="numbertext"></div>
                                <img src="" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="mySlides2 fade">
                                <div class="numbertext"></div>
                                <img src="" />

                            </div>

                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,'mySlides2')">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1,'mySlides2')">&#10095;</a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-info">
                            <div class="modal-details">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much its almost working but now my slides appear like images one after the others and not like slideshow !! Do you have an idea of why?

Comment: not not using bootstrap modals. check my modal code below in the comment

Comment: just added my modal code to question. Can you check please?

Comment: Ok, I found the bug remove `dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";` it will work after that